# Creating N days interval function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I am trying to create a function in postgresql that returns a set of dates in between two dates with a certain interval. For example, If I pass on these two date parameters like `most_recent_day = 2020-01-10` and `mininum_day = 2020-01-01` and this interval parameter `n_day_group_interval = 5`, the function will return the following set:

```
2020-01-10
2020-01-08
2020-01-06
2020-01-04
2020-01-02
```

Following was my attempt that gives an `syntax error at or near "end"`. Thank you for your help.

```
create function get_n_day_group_dates(most_recent_day date, minimum_day date, n_day_group_interval varchar)
returns table (
    n_day_group_dates date
              )
    as $body$
    begin
        return query

    SELECT
                      date_trunc('day'::text, dd.dd)::date AS n_day_group_dates
               FROM

                    LATERAL generate_series(most_recent_day,
                        minimum_day,
                       '-'||n_day_group_interval||' day'::interval) dd(dd)
end;
    $body$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. LATERAL is not required and `date_trunc('day', ..)` is the same as casting to `date`.

To create an interval based on a variable, the easiest way is to use `make_interval()`

```
create function get_n_day_group_dates(most_recent_day date, minimum_day date, n_day_group_interval varchar)
returns table (n_day_group_dates date)
as $body$
  SELECT g.dt::date
  FROM generate_series(most_recent_day,
                       minimum_day,
                       make_interval(days => n_day_group_interval) as g(dt);
$body$
language sql;
```